# Install SQL Express in docker file

Tags: .net, sql-server, linux, windows, docker

I have the following docker file in Visual studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 1433

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src", ""]
COPY ["NuGet.Config", ""]
COPY ["test", "test"]
COPY ["*.sln", ""]

#RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.Config  "Security.WebApi/Security.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/WebApi.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

#### Run all tests in sln   ####
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet test "HSB.Webapi.sln" "--logger:trx"
WORKDIR "/src/src/Webapi.WebApi"
#### END OF TESTS ####

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Webapi.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Webapi.WebApi.dll"]
```

This gives me a container where I can build and run my .NET application.

However, now I want to install SQL Express as well. How can I do this in the docker file above? I want to install and start sql express when the container is started.

I have tried to add this:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
COPY ./create-db.sql .
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV sa_password fisk1234
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433
CMD /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

But that don't work.

Comment: The best practice is to run the two (web server, database) in different containers, but manage them together. Tons of articles on the right approach, https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-linking-containers-69a4e5bf50fb

Comment: At least the question you have [since deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61709384/2029983) told us what the error was. "that don't work" tells us nothing about *why* or *how* what you do isn't working (as you expect). Considering you've omited that inforamtion, however, I assume that the results are different. Deleting and reposting questions isn't really what SO is for though. There is an [edit] feature you should be making use of if you want to improve your question.

Comment: @Larnu: Sorry for that. The error was that I could not connect to the database. When I "loged in" to my container, it seemd like database-server was not installed.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't add another `FROM` to your main dockerfile to install Sql Server, because that create new layer in temporary image and drop all its previous layers.

So you have two choices:

1. Install Sql Server with `apt-get` command in final layer of your docker file using `RUN` command (not recommended):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mssql-server=(version_number)

   // and many more startup configurations ...
   ```
2. Use Docker Compose as described in [Docker documentation sample](https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/) (**straight and recommended**)